# YUI 3.10 Simple scroll animation

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation, scroll, yui

We moved our project to latest YUI version and some problem which should be trivial became night mare.

Goal: Click on 'back to top' element need to move our users to top element

Animated Scroll inside Firefox doesn't work any more. There is the code:

```
navElem.on('click', function(el){
    var y = 1000;
    anim.set('to', { scroll: [0, y - Y.one('.fixed_header').get('scrollHeight')] });
    anim.run();
});
```

This code works in Google Chrome.

I have read somewhere that '`scroll`' as `anim` option was removed with new version.
If we can't use `anim` anymore, how can we created an animated scroll?

Comment: It seems to work with YUI 3.10.3 http://jsbin.com/ezokab/1/. Can you create a jsbin/jsfiddle example that we can look at?

Comment: Thx for the reply, I took a look at your example i found a problem. Anim.node property was set to body element and after i changed it into 'win'(as in your example) it works again. thx again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should point Anim's `node` attribute to "win" rather than "body", ie:

```
var anim = new Y.Anim({
  duration: 0.5,
  node: 'win',
  easing: 'easeBoth',
  to: {
    scroll: [0, 0]
  }
});
```

YUI then knows how to normalize across browsers which node to scroll.